# Subdomain not working

Tags: domain-name-system

I have set up a sub domain in plesk and it has added a a-name record in plesk but I get the 'oops link is broken' page in chrome.

I have my domain name registered with provider A and my server with provider B. Provider A(where plesk is located) has an A name for my subdomain. I'm not sure that matters though because provider A do not host the domain.

Should I set up a sub.domain.com A name with provider B?
Could this be the reason why the subdomain isn't working?

Answer (score 2):

DNS records will mostly be available about 2 days (globally) after creating it so @alfred that could be the reason you see "non-authoritative" response.

Per your last comment, you said "I just added sub.domain.com IPADDRESS". Wait for around 2 days and check again. If you are in the same country where your DNS resides, 1 day may be the most that you'll wait. But globally, it takes 2 days for the DNS to be replicated.

Hope that helps.
Ismael

Comment: Two days?! Your caching servers are in sad shape.  A new domain should show up almost everywhere within an hour or so.  I reliably see ~30 minutes over here.

Comment: @Bill, I said 2 days because that's the global average for full propagation of the DNS and I know that you know it too :)

Answer (score 1):

Do a nslookup to narrow down the problem.

## nslookup sub.domain.com

If it doesn't resolve I would check the DNS entry. If it does resolve then the problem could be with your webserver not configured for that sub.domain.

Comment: I get "returned a non-authoritative response". So no, the NSLOOKUP returns nothing.

Comment: I just added sub.domain.com IPADDRESS. I don't think this is the right way to add that record though?

Comment: For authoritative response use `dig sub.example.com @DNSforDomain`

Answer (score 1):

What are the nameservers for `domain.com`? If you want to see if the zone file has been updated properly you can try `nslookup sub.domain.com ns1.provider-a.com` which should give you the IP you've configured the sub-domain for in Plesk.

If it is then it's just a waiting game (or you can modify your hosts file) otherwise you'll need to update the domain name's zone file.